# Bitwarden automatically opening new tab in Geckodriver Firefox window

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, firefox-profile

I'm trying to write automated tests that work on Chrome, Edge, and Firefox using Selenium and the relevant drivers.  However, when I run the tests on Firefox, the new browser window opens up the desired page and then a [Bitwarden page](https://bitwarden.com/browser-start/) in a separate tab.  This separate tab opening seems to effect how my test is executing.  Does anyone know how to prevent it from opening?

What I tried:

- Uninstalled the extension from the standalone browser, but it would reappear anyway in the automated instance.  My IT department said they created some system to make sure it stays installed.  How do I make this tab not open?
- Cleared the addons.json file from both locally stored profiles.
  What I am trying to avoid:
- Making my test exit this tab every time I run it.
- Messing with the registry.  Kinda want to avoid angering IT if I can.

Anyone know about how to fix this?

Comment: Run the tests from a virtual machine which does not have Bitwarden installed, if that does not violate company policy.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Not a bad idea, though I don't know if I want to ask them about it.  Also, it is not the most user-friendly, easily repeatable solution given that our QA department doesn't really use VMs already.

Comment: After installing Google's VirtualBox and creating a VM with another OS, I was pleasantly surprised how quickly and easily it worked on the first try. However, you could create a standard prepackaged VBox, or other https://alternativeto.net/software/virtualbox/, environment, and install on each QA machine. Of course, as you state, this is a *new* procedure, and requires perhaps 40 GB for the package. Or you could talk to IT about having them temporarily disable BitWarden on QA machines just for the duration of the test...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came to a solution.  Between the point where I open the browser driver and test, I placed the following code (Python) to switch the currently focused tab to the correct tab:

```
windows = self.driver.window_handles

if (len(windows) > 1):
  self.driver.switch_to.window(windows[0])
```

If the length of the list of tabs is greater than 1, the Bitwarden tab is open, and I switch to the first tab, which is the target tab I want to test on.  It doesn't really fix the root of the issue (that isn't really an easy solution), but it does return focus to the correct tab so that there are no more tab-related errors on Firefox.